# Extracting price in span using selenium python?

Tags: python, html, selenium, web-scraping

I'm trying to obtain the price text in the following html code:

```
<span class="item-price js-variant-price" content="79.95" itemprop="price">79,95 TL</span>
```

Using the code, i have this

```
prices2=driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//span[@class='item-price.js-variant-price'")
```

but so far it can't get the "79.96" value, what am I doing wrong?
[image]

Comment: Can you confirm the url of the page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your selector

```
"//span[@class='item-price.js-variant-price'"
```

is incorrect:

1. You missed closing square bracket
2. In XPath predicate you don't need to separate class names with dot

Correct XPath would be

```
"//span[@class='item-price js-variant-price']"
```

Also note that Price value might come from XHR so you might need to implement [Wait](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html#waits) to get it